# How can I set the position of my image in an <img> attribute?

Tags: html, image, html-table

This is my code:

```
<td class='buttons'><img src='images/buttons.png' alt='del' id='buttons_del' width='25'       height='25'></td>
<td class='buttons'><img src='images/buttons.png' alt='add' id='buttons_del' width='25' height='25'></td>
```

[This is a link to the image I'm using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgrDR.jpg)

**UPDATE:**
I want to select a part of the image not the whole image.

Comment: could you be a little more specific about what you want?

Comment: also I deleted the css tag because this is not css

Comment: with css you can set the background position, but i didnt know how to use it with a <img> attribute.

Comment: When you use the `style` attribute, you can put css inline. Also `<img>` is a tag not an attribute. Check what I did below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
a img{
 position: relative;
}
a.two img{
 left: -25px;
}
a.three img{
 left: -50px;
}
a.four img{
 left: -75px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="#" class="button one"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y8ewSl4.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="button two"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y8ewSl4.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="button three"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y8ewSl4.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="button four"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y8ewSl4.png" /></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean this?

```
<img src='images/buttons.png' style="position: absolute; top: 20; left: 20;" alt='del' id='buttons_del' width='25' height='25'></td>
```

change the top and left property to whatever you need